# Zapier - Input data sorting

Tags: zapier

Here is what happens:

I am using a very cool plugin in my Shopify store that allows you to customise your product following a sequence of steps.

**To illustrate**
[image]

Problem is that all of this information is not sorted for Zapier. Essentially it displays as this:

**The issue**
[image]

They come as " Line Items Properties Values " and "Line Items Properties Names" and when pasted they come as an array.

What I would need to do is to match those Names with their Values. And if possible be able then to select in the GUI of Zapier.

So instead of having these fields and values

```
"Line Properties Names" -> "Project Title","Project Description","Ebook Type"....

"Line Items Properties Values" -> "Sherlock Holmes","A story in London..", "Standard Book"...
```

Having these fields and values:

```
"Project Title" -> "Sherlock Holmes"
"Project Description" -> "A story in London.."
"Ebook Type" -> "Standard Ebook"
```

Would it be possible?

Thank you for your time

**UPDATE**

**For clarification purposes**

So, in this order there are 3 different products. Separated by []. Values within the product can vary, for instance if a customer decides to not fill the field of " Project Details ", then Project Details Keys and Value wont display. Resulting essentially in products with different amount of keys and values.

Here is an example: (As you can see the first product has a different set of values as the second product)

**Input data**

```
Input data Values: ["1","ebook1524837342394","Ebook~~//www.shappify-cdn.com/images/282516/127828455/001_Ebook Technical 325x325 (1).png~~ebook","Technical Ebook","Technical 15K - $450.00","All Inclusive Package - $149.00","Cookbook Instant Pot"],["ebook1524837342394"],["Detective Story based in London......","Sherlock Holmes","No Addons","No Package","10000 Words - $270.00","Fiction Book","Ebook~~//www.shappify-cdn.com/images/282516/127828453/001_Ebook Standard 325x325.png~~ebook","ebook1524837304725","1","https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0012/8814/2906/uploads/7ddee14d6e5d6c5e4396981d1702c375.jpg"]

 Input data Keys: ["_master_builder","_builder_id","_builder_info","Ebook Type","Word Count","Upgrade","Project Title"],["_builder_id"],["Project Details","Project Title","Addons","Upgrade","Word Count","Ebook Type","_builder_info","_builder_id","_master_builder","Upload your file here"]
```

**What I want to do**

I want to match the key with their value and be able to select them on the Zapier GUI.

**Current output with the code proposed**

[Output 1stpart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyLpO.png)

[Output 2ndpart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3s1J.png)

[Output 3rdpart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uljg9.png)

[Output 4thpart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvSrJ.png)

**Expected Output**

`[{"_master_builder":"1","_builder_id":"ebook1524837342394","_builder_info":"Ebook~~//www.shappify-cdn.com/images/282516/127828455/001_Ebook Technical 325x325 (1).png~~ebook"...}]`

Appreciate your help guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah! So this is a little trickier than it looked at first, but it's not bad. There are two gotchas:

- Your data is coming in as a string
- that string is made of multiple array objects, but isn't itself a valid array object

So once we parse it out correctly, it's not too bad.

```js
// just used for testing outside zapier
// these are comma separated strings
const inputData = {
  keys: '_master_builder,_builder_id,_builder_info,Ebook Type,Word Count,Upgrade,Project Title,_builder_id,Project Details,Project Title,Addons,Upgrade,Word Count,Ebook Type,_builder_info,_builder_id,_master_builder,Upload your file here',
  values: '1,ebook1524837342394,Ebook~~//www.shappify-cdn.com/images/282516/127828455/001_Ebook Technical 325x325 (1).png~~ebook,Technical Ebook,Technical 15K - $450.00,All Inclusive Package - $149.00,Cookbook Instant Pot,ebook1524837342394,Detective Story based in London......,Sherlock Holmes,No Addons,No Package,10000 Words - $270.00,Fiction Book,Ebook~~//www.shappify-cdn.com/images/282516/127828453/001_Ebook Standard 325x325.png~~ebook,ebook1524837304725,1,https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0012/8814/2906/uploads/7ddee14d6e5d6c5e4396981d1702c375.jpg'
}

// arrays must be the same length
const zipArrays = (a, b) => {
  let res = {}
  a.forEach((val, i) => {
    res[val] = b[i]
  })
  return res
}

// have to convert strings to actual arrays
// this will blow up if any of the data has commas in it
const keys = inputData.keys.split(',')
const vals = inputData.values.split(',')

// now we have real arrays

const result = {}

// copy keys onto the result, overwriting old ones
Object.assign(result, zipArrays(keys, vals))

console.log(result)
/*
  { _master_builder: '1',
    _builder_id: 'ebook1524837304725',
    _builder_info: 'Ebook~~//www.shappify-cdn.com/images/282516/127828453/001_Ebook Standard 325x325.png~~ebook',
    'Ebook Type': 'Fiction Book',
    'Word Count': '10000 Words - $270.00',
    Upgrade: 'No Package',
    'Project Title': 'Sherlock Holmes',
    'Project Details': 'Detective Story based in London......',
    Addons: 'No Addons',
    'Upload your file here': 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0012/8814/2906/uploads/7ddee14d6e5d6c5e4396981d1702c375.jpg' }
*/

// return result
```

As is, there's a lot of repeated keys keys so the output is smaller than the input. You can also tweak this code to match your input better if you want to group the output differently.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for getting on this. I got an Error: 
SyntaxError: Unexpected token _ in JSON at position 1. And this additional comments Object.parse (native)
  theFunction (eval at <anonymous> (/var/task/index.js:52:23), <anonymous>:25:19)
  eval (eval at <anonymous> (/var/task/index.js:52:23), <anonymous>:64:20)
  Domain.<anonymous> (/var/task/index.js:53:5)
  Domain.run (domain.js:221:14)
  module.exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:51:5)

Comment: huh. maybe it's not a string coming in? can you try and get some diagnostic info about the input? you can `return {type: typeof inputData.Keys}`. I'm working a little bit in the dark here

Comment: Yep, says string

Comment: uhh maybe try `const keys = JSON.parse('[' + inputData.Keys + ']')`, if it's tripping over the backticks? i tested in node 6 but who knows

Comment: The other thing you could change if you have control over the other's apps output is to pass an actual json string rather than `[1],[2],[3]`, which is invalid

Comment: Tried like that as well. Unfortunately having the same error

Comment: What's your zap id?

Comment: Sure, my Zap ID is 36247411. Thank you xavdid. The order in the example is defaulted. If you pull sample again, you will find another order consisting in 3 book configurations for test purposes.

Comment: ok, so it turns out your data was just run of the mill comma separated strings. That's not a great way to transmit data, but it's a little more sane than arrays next to each other

Comment: You are awesome @xavdid. Thank you so much! How do I deal now with the other book. The one on the first part of the array?

Comment: Honestly I would change how you store the data. Right now it looks like there's no concrete way to separate the books, which means it's hard to process them. Since you control the output of the trigger (a rare advantage) I'd try sending an array of objects or something, or at least some of the arrays you'd had before. Takes the guesswork out.

Comment: One question @xavdid, what if the fields were always the same size? Then would it be possible to separate them?. There would be only one "extra field" that could be omitted for this task, which is the field " Upload your file here " along with his correspondent value " the link ", so this lead me to think. What if we could remove that part from the equation and just process the rest? Some code that would say Omit: "Upload your file here" from the keys, and from values omit those containing "cdn.shopify.com" . If that is possible then I think I got the final solution.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible with a `for` loop. Try this.

In your [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqoLw.jpg), define the first box as values and the second as keys. Remove the `var inputData...` lines before running the code step.

```js
var inputData = {"keys": ["First", "Second", "Third"],
                "values": ["One", "Two", "Three"]
                };
//Remove the lines above before pasting in the Code step. 
//You will need to configure it in the Zap.

var product = {};
for (var i = 0; i < inputData.keys.length; i++) {
  var commonkey = inputData.keys[i];
  product[commonkey] = inputData.values[i];
}
console.log(JSON.stringify([product]));
   
// already available in the zapier scope
output = [product]
```

Comment: @fabian-c If this answer solved your problem, make sure to upvote it and select it as correct ([info here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers))

Comment: Thank you Kaycee. I followed your steps but there seems to be an error: We had trouble sending your test through. Please try again. Error: 
You must return a single object or array of objects.

Comment: I've tweaked the code to work in Zapier scripting - need to always return an array!

Comment: it looks like the characters of the keys are being iterated rather than the keys as array items. Can you update your question with a more complete version of the input(s), expected output, and the code you're using so it can be looked at as a whole? the comments aren't the best place to share that.